# Disable Jenkins Office 365 Connector Notifications based on time

Tags: jenkins, office365connectors

I have a FREESTYLE Jenkins job (i.e. not a pipeline job) that is leveraging the Office 365 Connector to notify events.
In the Advanced Configuration there is a section to only trigger using Macros (token macro).

[image]

I am trying to figure out how I can use this to only trigger notifications during a certain time period of the day? Say 9am to 5pm.

Or any other way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to disable notifications at certain times? you will lose the relevant data. Instead you can silence the edge client (teams for example) during the unwanted hours - and still have the notification available..

Comment: I want to disable notifications to a Teams channel at night when all our builds run (too many notifications) .  If there is a build during the day I want a channel to be notified to inform that group.  So you are saying I can modify Teams not to accept messages at certain times?